# Which Exchange Email apps for iPhone 5 allow advanced font and layout controls?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation, exchange-activesync

What I need in my Microsoft Exchange 2010 mail client:

- send e-mails in the text font I want
- send e-mails with my HTML signature
- reply to e-mails without unformatting the e-mail being replied to
- having the sent e-mail look just as it was sent by Microsoft Outlook itself
- no artifacts like having the replied e-mail sent as an HTML attachment

Coming from an Android, I had this with [Touchdown](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nitrodesk.droid20.nitroid).

What do you recommend for iPhone 5? What's the best, well integrated with the device, Exchange 2010 mail client?

Comment: I'm afraid the only integrated email client in iOS is the default one. It does work very well with Exchange servers, but it does not fulfil all your requirements.

Comment: Well integrated in the sense that shows notifications, alerts for meetings... Those kind of things, without having to open the application.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Mail+ for Outlook](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mail+-for-outlook/id428974099?mt=8). It is similar to the native iOS experience. Though it currently doesn't offer all of the features you mentioned, I know there is a new update coming by the end of February which will have rich text editing and better reply experiences. Apple severely limits the ability to use push notifications, so don't expect too many iOS mail clients to provide.

Comment: Does it offer _any_ of the listed features?

Answer (score -2):

[Altamail](http://mobile.eurosmartz.com/products/altamail.html) might be another solution to look at.

Comment: If you need to add information to your answer you can just press edit on the previous answer and add that information.

Comment: Please don't just post an app name and a link, but also explain why you are recommending this app.